# Aptana //novalidate option

Tags: javascript, eclipse, aptana, processing.js

I'm writing Processing.js code using Eclipse (with the Aptana plugin), and I'm a little confused by this option in the Javascript preferences:

> Enable error filtering inside //novalidate comments

Using Processing.js allows me (and occasionally forces me - for example, it uses the Java "void" instead of the Javascript "function" for method declarations) to do some funky things to javascript syntax that the validator doesn't like. I've got a bunch of error messages that I'd like to silence, but I'd rather use the Eclipse editor because the rest of my site is there.

I've tried sticking "//novalidate" before, after, after the semicolon on the same line, and even at the beginning of the file, but it has no effect. I've also tried adding exclude rules in Preferences -> Validation, but that doesn't seem to do anything, nor does turning off "Javascript problems" in Problems -> Configure Contents... (which I'd like to avoid, because I'm doing regular javascript elsewhere on my site). I can't find any documentation for "//novalidate" on the Aptana website - does anyone have any idea how to use this properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Aptana Support](http://www.aptana.com/support) methods?

Comment: Yes - a couple people there have mentioned //novalidate, but nobody has explained how to use it.